# ReferenceError: documentId is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-functions

Olá, estou tentando criar uma Firebase function para meu app em flutter enviar notificação para o token que esta em uma subcoleção sem especificar o document. Em dart eu consigo usar "documentId", porém na função em javascript me retornou "ReferenceError: documentId is not defined". Como faço para acessar essa subcoleção sem especificar o documento? Desde já agradeço.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var msgData;


exports.chatTrigger = functions.firestore.document(
     'chat/{chatId}/users/{usersId}/messages/{messagesId}'
).onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
   msgData = snapshot.data();

return 

  admin.firestore().collection('chat').document(documentId)
  .collection('users').document(documentId)
  .collection('messages').get().then((snapshots) => {
     var tokens = [];
     if (snapshots.empty) {
        console.log('No Devices');
        return false;


     } else {
      for (var token of snapshots.docs) {
          tokens.push(token.data().token);
      }

      var payload = {
         "notification": {
             "title": msgData.name,
             "body": msgData.title,
             "sound": "default"
          },
          "data": {
             "sendername": msgData.name,
             "message": msgData.title,
         }
       }

       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
          console.log('Pushed them all');
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       })
     }

   })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variável `documentId` não parece ter sido declarada em lugar algum do teu script, logo você não criou tal variável, então vai dar `ReferenceError` mesmo

O que você quer é provavelmente isto:

```
admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()
```

Conforme é documentado: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldPath#.documentId

Você poderia setar no começo do script:

```
var msgData;
var documentId = admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId();

...
```

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, realmente não sabia, dai preciso referenciar o caminho para o documento?